# Computing the genus of a manifold?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, lie-groups, lattices-in-lie-groups

I was reading [week 193](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/week193.html) of John Baez' blog, and he mentions that $E_8$ can be realized as the symmetry group of a certain 57-dimensional manifold;

> Recently, some mathematical physicists have been studying a construction
>   of E8 as the symmetries of a 57-dimensional manifold equipped with extra
>   structure:
>
> 1. Murat Gunaydin, Koepsell and Hermann Nicolai, Conformal and
>      quasiconformal realizations of exceptional Lie groups,
>      Commun. Math. Phys. 221 (2001), 57-76, also available as hep-th/0008063
> 2. Thomas A. Larsson, Structures preserved by exceptional Lie algebras,
>      available as math-ph/0301006.

It turns out that it's very curious that the dimension happens to be 57, and I was wondering what the genus of this manifold might be?  Would it be easy to compute?  Perhaps it too is an interesting number related to all this Lie theory business.

Comment: What do you mean by the genus of a manifold of dimension higher than $2$? Typically this term is reserved for surfaces, although there is also the notion of arithmetic and geometric genus of a variety.

Comment: If I remember it correctly, this 57-dimensional manifold is one of the flag-manifolds of $E8$. Cohomology rings (if this is what you care about) of flag-manifolds of complex simple Lie groups are well-understood.

Comment: Oops!  I didn't realize genus in the usual sense doesn't make sense for higher dimensions, but now that you mention it that makes perfect sense.  I'm aware of some of the other notions of genus, so I guess I can look into that.  
I've only recently picked up some introductory works on cohomology, but I suppose working towards computations with this manifold can be my motivation moving forward.